# How to get a wand with at least 150 vis in Thaumcraft Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm playing the Thaumcraft 4 mod in ftb. I'm trying to make a silverwood staff with thaumium caps and it says that I need 144 of each vis to craft. I thought, ok I'll just make a quarts staff with gold caps and I can make it. Well I did but then I realized that you can't place staff's in the arcane workbench. So now I'm stuck because my strongest wand (Silverwood w/ thaumium caps) only has 100 vis capacity. Is there a way to decrease the vis required or a wand with at least 150 vis?

Answer (score 2):

The answer for base Thaumcraft is to use a scepter.  The easy route is iron-capped wood wand -> gold capped greatwood wand -> gold capped silverwood wand -> thaum capped silverwood scepter.

Note that thaumaturge's robe, legging, boots plus the googles of revealing all provide additional discounts.

Answer (score 1):

You need gear that gives you vis discounts. Sanguine helmet, full robes, and a fuelled harness should be enough. If you got Forbidden Magic installed, you could also use a Thaumium Bossed Infernal Wand, and you'd have over 200 vis. With Advanced Thaumaturgy (another mod, hasn't been updated to 1.7 yet, I think) you could craft a Mercurial Wand. It's not easy to make, but it can hold 1000 vis. Ichor wand is another option...

Also note that frugal foci are bugged in versions older than 1.7, so that could be an issue.